# Google app script stop running after close browser

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets add-on to process large amount of data. When a user submits a task, it might take a long time to process. They might close sidebar or even browser. How can I make the app script keeps running even add-on is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your script set a near future trigger with the function in question and the add-on poll for successful completion of previous processing on timeout or startup (using hashed script properties say).

No matter if the sheet is open or closed the triggered function runs as a standalone process.